# python ecdsa - How to derive a public key from a signature and a message

Tags: python, cryptography, ecdsa

Given a signature and message, it should be possible to derive a public key. How can this been done with the `ecdsa` library in python, or even more generally, how can this be done in python using any library?

Right now I have something like

```
from ecdsa import SigningKey, SECP256k1

sk = SigningKey.generate(curve=SECP256k1)
vk = sk.verifying_key

msg = b"Some arbitrary message"
signature = sk.sign(msg)

print("Signing (Private) key: ", sk.to_string().hex())
print("Verifying (Public) key: ", vk.to_string().hex())
print("Signature: ", signature.hex())
print(vk.verify(signature, msg))
```

that signs and verifies a message which is great, but I'm looking for something like

```
vk2 = vk_from_signature(signature, msg, curve=SECP256k1)
if vk.to_string().hex() == vk2.to_string().hex():
    print("SUCCESS")
```

Comment: Public key recovery is described in [SEC1, pp. 47](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) and [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38909). The ecdsa library provides the [`Signature#recover_public_keys()`](https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa/blob/master/src/ecdsa/ecdsa.py#L78) method, which determines candidate keys. For more support, Python libraries with [Bitcoin or Ethereum relation](https://wizardforcel.gitbooks.io/practical-cryptography-for-developers-book/content/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-examples.html) are probably of interest.